# MVC -- Displaying view in a new tab

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am completely new to MVC. I am developing one site. I am using database behind model.

Problem:
I want to display view (razor syntax) in a new tab when an user clicks a button. I am using view bag for this. If view bag has any data,I want to display that in a new tab.Otherwise an alert should come in a current page.please help me to come out of this.

Thanx  in advance.

Comment: please include relevant code

Answer (score 2):

check through jquery if your viewbag has any data use this

`window.open(url, "_blank");`